# Do "radical" and "extremist" imply violence? If so, is one more violent than the other?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

I'm looking at the noun form of the words "radical" and "extremist" and trying to figure out if one is inherently more violent than the other or if neither really implies violence at all. It seems like these standard definitions don't really fit in today's context, but maybe I'm wrong. I pulled these two noun definitions from dictionary.com. Do both words automatically imply violent methods in a today's context? If so, is one inherently more violent than the other?  Is one more extreme than the other?

I pulled these definitions from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com)

> Radical
>
> 10.
>   a person who holds or follows strong convictions or extreme principles; extremist.
>
> 11.
>   a person who advocates fundamental political, economic, and social reforms by direct and often uncompromising methods.
>
> Extremist
>
> 1.
>   a person who goes to extremes, especially in political matters.
>
> 2.
>   a supporter or advocate of extreme doctrines or practices.

Comment: *Inherently*, no word is more violent than any other word. Because *inherently*, no word has any meaning at all. You will need to look at the context. That's where the meaning comes from. Context as in the actual words. "Today's context" is not a context. That, in itself, has no meaning whatsoever unless you specify what meaning it is supposed to have. Is "cat" more violent than "dog" in today's context?

Comment: Both terms imply persons or groups with political agendas, if that helps with the context at all.  I'm trying to view the words in the context of any organization in today's world that has any sort of political agenda.

Comment: "Extremist" is usually taken to mean something more extreme than "radical", and perhaps more inclined to violence.  Though neither term implies violence (and "radical" doesn't imply non-violence).

Comment: *Radical* refers to the root of something. Acting radical means going to/acting on/looking at the root of something. It can be contrasted with taking action on, or looking at, only superficial matters.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the word "radical" is frequently used to describe politicians and preachers who hold intolerant, narrow and unbending views but who do not necessarily promote violence.

The word "extremist" tends to be associated more with figures who unhesitatingly use and promote violence as a means to an end, frequently with groups advocating insurrection.

The problem is that these days any hostile group is likely to be labelled in the media as extremists or terrorists. The word "enemy" has gone out of fashion. National governments frequently insist that they are fighting extremists or terrorists even when government forces are doing most of the terrorising.

But my answer to your question is that the word "extremist" implies more violence than "radical".

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster Unabridged defines *extremist* in terms of *radical*:

> **extremist**, *n.*:  an adherent or advocate of extremism; especially :  **radical**

In turn, it defines *radical* as:

> **radical**, *n.*:
>
> **4**:  one that is radical: such as
>
> **a** :  one that advocates a decided and often extreme change from existing, usual, or traditional views, habits, conditions, or methods
>
> **b** :  one that advocates radical and sweeping changes in laws, institutions, and methods of government with the least delay

As you see, *extremist* and *radical* are effectively synonymous, and neither is explicitly violent, nor is violence implied by either term.

As an example, members of the [House Freedom Caucus](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2015/10/20/house-freedom-caucus-what-is-it-and-whos-in-it/) are often described as extremist Republicans, but they're more obstructionist than actually violent.